# Poor performance from flat list with minimal data

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, watermelondb

I am a little lost trying to solve the problem of my tasks app. Users can create tasks, and these tasks immediately get added to the database. The tasks are then rendered out on the in 2 Flat lists on the home view. The Flat lists have been moved out into there own separate components and are re used twice in the home view in order to render out a list of tasks in progress and a list of completed tasks.

When users decide to create a task, there is a lag when the item add to database function is called. And then another delay for when the item is rendered out onto the home page view. I could understand this there was a lot of items in the database however this problem starts with as little as 2 tasks created and get progressively worse.

I am unsure how to resolve these performance issues. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I have tried using the react dev tools, I've  attached below the profile export (I was unsure what is was really doing but got a performance clip of adding a task). The peformance report was made with only ~24 items in the database. The problem is less severe on an actual mobile device, my galaxy s9, however there is still poor performance with too few items.

Section of home view

```
<ScrollView f={1} space="$4" paddingHorizontal={"$4"} mt={"$5"} theme="neutral">
  <DatabaseProvider database={database}>
    <EnhancedTaskList
      title="In Progress"
      userId={userId}
      filterQuery="is_completed"
      filter={false}
    />
    <EnhancedTaskList
      title="Is Completed"
      userId={userId}
      filterQuery="is_completed"
      filter
    />
  </DatabaseProvider>
</ScrollView>;
```

EhancedTaskList

```
const enhance = compose(
  withDatabase,
  withObservables(["userId"], ({ database, userId, filterQuery, filter }) => ({
    tasks: database
      .get("tasks")
      .query(
        Q.where(filterQuery, filter),
        Q.where("user_id", userId),
        Q.where("is_archived", Q.notEq(true))
      )
      .observe(),
    archiveTasksCount: database
      .get("tasks")
      .query(
        Q.where(filterQuery, filter),
        Q.where("user_id", userId),
        Q.where("is_archived", Q.notEq(true))
      )
      .observeCount(),
  }))
);

const EnhancedTaskList = enhance(TaskList);

export default EnhancedTaskList;
```

TaskList

```
const Task = ({ currentTask }) => {
  const [taskInput, setTaskInput] = useState<any>(currentTask.title);
  const task = useTaskStore((state) => state.task);
  const setTask = useTaskStore((state) => state.setTask);

  const updateTask = async function (
    updatedTitle: string,
    taskId: string
  ): Promise<void> {
    const task: any = await database.get("tasks").find(taskId);
    await task.updateTask(updatedTitle);

    const updateTask = {
      taskId: task.taskId,
      edit: false,
    };
    setTask(updateTask);
  };

  return (
    <YStack width="100%" padding={0} theme="primary">
      {task.taskId == currentTask.id && task.edit ? (
        <Input
          width="100%"
          m={0}
          onChangeText={(text) => {
            setTaskInput(text);
          }}
          value={taskInput}
          onSubmitEditing={() => {
            void updateTask(taskInput, currentTask.id);
          }}
          editable={task.taskId == currentTask.id ? task.edit : false}
        />
      ) : (
        <Text paddingLeft="$4">{taskInput}</Text>
      )}
    </YStack>
  );
};

const TaskList = (props: TaskListProps) => {
  const { title, tasks, archiveTasksCount } = props;

  // Collapse sections
  const [isCollapsed, setIsCollapsed] = useState<boolean>(false);

  return (
    <YStack>
      <Pressable
        onPress={() => {
          setIsCollapsed(!isCollapsed);
        }}
      >
        <XStack jc="space-between" ai="center" alignContent="center">
          <SizableText size="$5" fontWeight="bold">
            {title}
          </SizableText>
          {archiveTasksCount > 0 && title === "Completed" && (
            <Button
              size="$2"
              onPress={() => {
                void archiveTasks();
              }}
              theme="neutral"
            >
              Archive
            </Button>
          )}
        </XStack>
      </Pressable>
      <Collapsible collapsed={isCollapsed}>
        <YGroup bordered size="$4" theme="primary" p={0}>
          <FlatList
            style={{ padding: 0, margin: 0 }}
            scrollEnabled={false}
            initialNumToRender={25}
            data={tasks}
            renderItem={({ item }) => {
              return (
                <CustomStyleSwipeableRow
                  taskTitle={item.title}
                  taskId={item.id}
                  isCompleted={item.isCompleted}
                >
                  <YGroup.Item>
                    <ListItem>
                      <Task currentTask={item} />
                    </ListItem>
                  </YGroup.Item>
                </CustomStyleSwipeableRow>
              );
            }}
          />
        </YGroup>
      </Collapsible>
    </YStack>
  );
};
```

[profiling-data.19-10-2023.21-58-25.json](https://github.com/Nozbe/WatermelonDB/files/13041686/profiling-data.19-10-2023.21-58-25.json)

Edit 1: I've added the key extractor to the flatlist, it does not make a difference.